# Pandas import error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pandas

[I installed pandas "pip install pandas" but it show error during import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2InO.png)

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual command / input / output / error as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the pip install as sudo:

```
    sudo pip install pandas
```

Then enter your password.